# Why does not work CActiveDataProvider after change criteria

Tags: php, yii, cactivedataprovider

This code work fine:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('id', 1);
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('User', array('criteria'=>$criteria));
foreach ($dataProvider->getData() as $value) var_dump($value->id);
```

But when I change criteria after create CActiveDataProvider instance this does not work:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('id', 1);
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('User', array('criteria'=>$criteria));
$criteria->compare('id', 2);
foreach ($dataProvider->getData() as $value) var_dump($value->id);
```

This return empty!
Why is this?

Comment: you are overwriting the criteria.

Comment: not overwriting, just adding a compare condition, your final condition is something like this : `id='1' AND id='2'`...

Comment: But I change criteria after create instance of CActiveDataProvider !

Comment: You should learn about references : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: @soju, Very thanks, If you post this comment via new answer, sure I check mark it for best answer ;) 
really my question was 'How use of one criteria for a CActiveDataProvider and then change some methods from same criteria and use it for another new instance of CActiveDataProvider.'
I read that article and find solution: $criteria2 = clone $criteria; $criteria2->compare('id', 2);

Comment: We couldn't guess this, you should have been more explicit :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any result since you are adding a condition to your criteria : generated SQL will look like this : `WHERE id='1' AND id='2'`

If you want to list user 1 and 2 you should try :

```
$criteria->compare('id', 2, false, 'OR');
```

Or simply use [`addInCondition`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail).

**EDIT** : as you said in your comment, instead of using the same criteria object, you can [clone it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

Comment: I think the `addInCondition` would be better: Instead of doing `$criteria->compare('id', 1);` `$criteria->compare('id', 2, false, 'OR');` you'll simply do `$criteria->addInCondition('id', array(1,2));`

Comment: but I don't have problem with work with criteria! I want use of one criteria for a CActiveDataProvider and then change some methods from same criteria and use it for another new instance of CActiveDataProvider.